# Not announcing raise on purpose

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, etiquette

Setting: You are playing 1$/2$ or 2$/4$ ish live cash game or 100$ to 500$ live tournament.

Pre Flop every one folds to you / you are UTG and you put in a single chip which is 5x the BB. After you put it in you say raise. In most casinos this would be ruled as a call, obviously most players would think your intention was raising.

Your intention is to look unexperienced in live play and to get the advantage of the aggressor image without paying the price. Obviously you would only do this with starting hand you do not want to protect.

**Question**
Would you consider this action as bad manner?

Comment: I can't imagine most players not seeing through that. We all know the one-chip-rule, so I certainly wouldn't assume the player intended a raise. True, it's easier for an experienced player to fake inexperience than the other way around, but it's still quite hard.

Comment: UTG if first to act pre flop so not sure how it is folded to you.

Comment: I meant if it is folded to you or you are UTG.

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish? You will fool them at most once.  You are already called by the big blind. You think this might fold out hands that otherwise would have called a min bet?

Comment: It is more of a gimmick, you can try to tilt someone who is already complaining about bad players. I was just curious how this "play" is seen in terms of manners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an attempted angle. Say "raise" when you know it should not apply is an angle. Not enough of an angle to get you a penalty but still an angle.

That is considered poor etiquette.

Not an angle that would give you any advantage in my opinion but it is still an attempted angle.

Another angle is to put out just over 1.5 and say "call".  You are forced to min raise but maybe fooled your opponent into thinking you were weaker than you are.  Again might not get you a penalty but it is still poor etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's going to be considered angle shooting in most places.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because most player who played longer than a full session (6 to 8 hour night) would have known that rule. One chip is a call.

You need to announce a raise if you want it to be a raise. Pretending you were actually raising never works because no dealer will allow that. One chip is a call. It's not really "angle shooting" because what angle? You would have to be playing against complete drunken amateurs for it to even have any effect. It's no more "angle shooting" than acting drunk and not being drunk... Or having a half-finished beer (but didn't actually drink any). Most angle-shooing carries such minor effect that it's negligible... This one especially so.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem pretty intentional to almost any player and would therefore have the opposite effect. Either:

a) Use this against experienced players to actually look weak

b) Use this against very weak players and an experienced dealer

c) Respect etiquette, work on your game and 'git gud kid'